# r hyphen in label of x axis

Tags: r, label, axis

The x axis label has hyphen. This is not what I wrote in my code:

```
temp = table(res$Methode, res$Bewertung)
tempf = ftable(res$Methode, res$Bewertung)
barplot(tempf , xlab="Bewertung", ylab="absolute Häufigkeit", cex.lab = 1.4, beside=TRUE, ylim = c(0,600), xlim=c(11.75,1.7), col = colour2) 
legend("top", legend=c("ohne LOD", "mit LOD"), horiz = TRUE, inset = c(0, 0), fill = rev(colour2), cex=1.4)
axis(1, at=c(11, 8, 5, 2),labels=c("sehr relevant", "mit­tel­mä­ßig relevant", "wenig relevant", "nicht relevant"), cex.axis=1.4)
```

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: When I type in in "mittelmä­ßig", I get `Error: invalid multibyte character in parser`. If it's copied/derived from somewhere else, typing it by hand may fix the issue, or stringi has some utilities for dealing with Unicode issues like this.

Comment: Try replacing the non-ascii characters with their unicode escapes (`\uxxxx`)?